# I created a program to convert reals to dollars and the float variable is incorrect

Tags: c++

I created a program to convert real(the Brazilian coin) to the dollar and the coins are 4 digits and the float variable is more:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs[]){
float fReal;
cout << "enter the cash in real: R$:";
cin >> fReal;
float fDollar = fReal / 3.90;
cout << "your cash in dollar(s): " << fDollar << endl; // Here i want 
//:.2f(from python) to the dollar value
cout << "Press enter to continue..." << endl;
cin.ignore(10, '\n');
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "please help me" with what? What is the issue?

Comment: Floating point math can be weird with currencies. It's better to work in the smallest units and divide by 100 (or whatever) only when displaying output. For example, use integers and store a value as 293 cents instead of $2.93.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(2)<< fDollar<<'\n';
```